# Make combo box in JavaFX display indented text items in a non-indented way

Tags: javafx, combobox

So I'm using ComboBox to create a list of items of which the user can choose one. The list is hierarchical/indented in the following way:

```
Header 1
    Item 1
    Item 2
    Header 1.1
        Item 1
        Item 2
Header 2
    Item 1
    Item 2
```

This looks good, but here comes the problem. When a user clicks on one of the indented items, the item is displayed WITH indentation. So the ComboBox displays, for example, the following:

```
  Item 1
```

That looks really bad. I want it to be displayed like this (without the preceding indentation):

Item 1

Code for running the program:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("interface.fxml"));

    ComboBox<String> genre1AddBook = new ComboBox<String>();
    ObservableList<String> genresAddBook;
    genresAddBook = FXCollections.observableArrayList("SKÖNLITTERATUR", "\tDeckare", "\tFantasy");
    genre1AddBook.getItems().addAll(genresAddBook);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(genre1AddBook);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

How can I make the ComboBox display the indented items without the indentation and still display a hierarchical/indented structure?

Comment: Post a [mre] please

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand exactly what was wrong with the post. What part of minimal reproducible example was wrong?

Comment: Post a reproducible example. Not sure what you want me to explain that isn't in the link.

Comment: You mean the code? Why?

Comment: Because no-one else knows how you have structured the objects you are displaying in the combo box, and what cell factories you are using to display them. We are not clairvoyant.\

Comment: Is that enought, what I posted? Im not sure how much one needs for this kind of question.

Comment: How is that reproducible? "Reproducible" means we can copy, paste, and run the code without modification. It needs to be complete.

Comment: No one wants to go out of their way to write code to solve your problem and even if they do there might not be any issues with the code they wrote because they structured everything differently. If you want a higher chance at someone helping you write a [mre] doesn't need to be and shouldnt be all of your code because the only code we need to see should be enough to reproduce the issue its not that hard it should be at least a single class with a stage, scene, and whatever components you need to reproduce the scenario in your case its Stage, Scene Combo box filled with strings

Comment: @Matt Presumably, though, the OP is not filling the combo box with strings, because the `String` class doesn't carry any information about the hierarchical structure they describe.

Comment: Allright. Maybe Im wrong here. But I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I dont want a ready made code. The exact solution doesnt have to be done with similar code to mine . Anything that accomplishes what I want suffices...

Comment: @James_D you're right if only there was some way for us to know how he setup his class

Comment: Allright, I added a runnable class. But there is nothing else interesting than what I posted before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the class you posted, you can use a `buttonCell` on the combo box that strips the whitespace from the string.

```
genre1AddBook.setButtonCell(new ListCell<>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText("");
        } else {
            setText(item.stripLeading());
        }
    }
});
```

But this is a really bad design; I assume in your real application you would not actually use `String` as the data class for your `ComboBox`, if the values in the combo box have additional data associated with them (such as the parent or child nodes in the hierarchical structure). You should set a cell factory on the combo box that indents the cells in the dropdown according to their position in the hierarchy, and a button cell which doesn't indent the text.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into cell factory and button cell. What is the above bad design?

Comment: Like I said, the bad design is using `String` as the data class for your combo box, when the items you place in the combo box have other data associated with them.

Comment: Aha, I get it. You make a lot of sense.